# merge the describe method output in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge, data-munging

I'm using pandas to do data munging and I can't seem to figure out what seems like a basic merge. Essentially, I have multiple describe methods  on a dataset.  The output of the describe method is shown below.  I used simple numbers for this example. The name of the column is the same (Metric4).

```
      Metric4
count 10
mean  15
std   28
min   86
25%   10
50%   12
75%   13
max   18

      Metric4
count 15
mean  26
std   26
min   86
25%   10
50%   12
75%   13
max   18
```

I want to merge these together is order to get an output that looks like the following:

```
      Metric4  Metric42
count 15       10
mean  26       15
std   26       28
min   86       86
25%   10       10
50%   12       12
75%   13       13
max   18       18
```

I guess I would like to change the column name to in order to differentiate the two, but the main problem I'm currently having is with merging. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you checked out the API? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather simple case of `merge`, in which you can supply the suffixes with the additional `suffixes=('', '2')` argument:

```
In [95]:

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'Metric4':np.random.randn(10)})
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Metric4':np.random.randn(10)})
In [96]:

print pd.merge(df0.describe(), df1.describe(), left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=('', '2'))
         Metric4   Metric42
count  10.000000  10.000000
mean    0.304794  -0.061428
std     1.536658   1.388435
min    -1.955994  -2.320610
25%    -1.102251  -1.357967
50%     0.718339   0.289702
75%     1.262556   1.211371
max     2.571758   1.341736
```